# Resharper clean code line breaks with properties and fields

Tags: resharper

Here is my issue.  I want to put line breaks between properties and not fields.

Here is what I am getting:

```
private string _field1;

private string _field2;

private string _field3;

public string Property1 { get; set; }

public string Property2 { get; set; }

public string Property3 { get; set; }
```

Here is what I want:

```
private string _field1;
private string _field2;
private string _field3;

public string Property1 { get; set; }

public string Property2 { get; set; }

public string Property3 { get; set; }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get Resharper to have this type of line breaks?  What I currently have is that the Resharper puts lines breaks between all of fields and properties or no line breaks.  I cannot seem to find the right settings to get what I want.

Comment: Both your code blocks look identical to me, but I think I know what you mean. I had a poke around the 'Blank Lines' settings under Resharper->Options->Languages->C#->Formatting Style but could only get all blank lines or none. I wasn't able to get different formatting for fields or properties. Just decide on one format and use it everywhere.

Comment: That is what I am doing now.  I just force the line break.

Comment: Issue to watch and vote is here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-98614

Answer (score 5):

Go to **ReSharper|Options** and under **Code Editing**, navigate to **C#→Formatting Style→Blank Lines**. Now, you need to change two separate options:

- Change the **Keep max blank lines in code** value to 0 (zero)
- Change the **Around single line field** value to 0 (zero)

... and you're done!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.  It only preserves the line breaks the way they are. I want to force the second formatting as is in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to ensure that **Keep existing line breaks** is not checked under **Line Breaks and Wrapping**.